# Twitter Tweets extraction with R - Not able to extract more number of tweets

Tags: r, twitter, tweets, twitter-r

I need around 10k tweets from twitter but i am not able to extract them.

Getting below warning message:

> In doRppAPICall("search/tweets", n, params = params, retryOnRateLimit
>   = retryOnRateLimit,  :   10000 tweets were requested but the API can only return 476

Is there any way to extract 10k tweets?

Answer (score 0):

See the [Twitter search API](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/api-reference/get-search-tweets.html), with a standard account you can only request tweets of the last 7 days or 180 tweets in a 15 minutes window with user auth (450 with app auth).

**Edit1:** It seems that I misunderstood the API description. You can make 180/450 requests a second does not mean you get 180/450 tweets, but that you can make 180/450 different API calls. The explanation to the phenomenon you are describing is also made in the above mentioned link:

> Please note that Twitter’s search service and, by extension, the Search API is not meant to be an exhaustive source of Tweets. Not all Tweets will be indexed or made available via the search interface.

For one keyword, Twitter may see only a few hundred as important, whereas for other keywords a few thounds may be interesting enough.

Comment: Thanks for the information , but when i try to extract data using some other keyword , i am able to extract 5k tweets...is there any specific reason ?